# How to add prefix and suffix to every element in array in Jinja2?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need a one-liner Jinja2 template for the following task which will used in Ansible.

I have a list of hostnames and want to add protocol and port to every one of them, then join the new string together.
From list `['host1', 'host2', 'host3']` and prefix `'https://'` and suffix `':1234'` i need the following string created: `'https://host1:1234,https://host2:1234',https://host3:1234'`.

What i put together from here and there is something like this:
`{{ ['host1', 'host2'] | map('string') | **** | join(',') }}` where **** is probably a map or a format filter, i just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any way to do this using strict Jinja.

If you're using Jinja from Python, the easiest solution is probably to define a custom filter:

```py
import jinja2

def strformat(v, fmt):
    return fmt % v

env = jinja2.Environment()
env.filters['strformat'] = strformat

hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
t = env.from_string('{{ hosts | map("strformat", "https://%s:1234") | join(",") }}')
print(t.render(hosts=hosts))
```

Running the above code produces:

```
https://host1:1234,https://host2:1234,https://host3:1234
```

---

Alternatively, just transform the list before you pass it in to your template:

```py
import jinja2

hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
formatted_hosts = [ 'https://%s:1234' % host for host in hosts]
t = jinja2.Template('{{ formatted_hosts | join(",") }}')
print(t.render(hosts=hosts, formatted_hosts=formatted_hosts))
```

This produces the same output.

---

If you happen to be using Jinja in Ansible, you can accomplish the same thing with the `regex_replace` filter:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    hosts: ['host1','host2','host3']
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ hosts | map("regex_replace", "^(.*)$", "https://\1:1234") | join(",") }}'
```

Comment: I missed to mention that i need the Jinja2 template in Ansible. Edited my question with that. However, the regex_replace filter doesn't seem to be part of the default Ansible package. Maybe it is version dependent. If there is no one-liner solution then i will need a loop.

Comment: The `regex_replace` filter is absolutely part of the default Ansible package. With nothing but Ansible installed (ansible-core 2.14.13) I can successfully run `ansible localhost -m debug -a 'msg={{ "hello world" | regex_replace("world", "moon") }}'`.